# Run script on multiple hosts using jenkins pipeline groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins pipeline groovy script.

I have a job param named 'HOSTNAMES' which will take some host name values separated by comma as an input. I need to execute some scripts on all these hosts in parallel mode. How to achieve this using jenkins groovy script. Pls guide me.

Comment: You will first have to connect all these slaves to Jenkins. [See how to](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72778132).

Comment: Yes.. Already slaves are configured in Jenkins. I just need to execute some scripts on all the hosts as requested above. Could you please share some logics on that?

Comment: I added the info as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all these nodes (hostnames) are connected to the Jenkins server and the `HOSTNAMES` parameter is a list of the node names (as they appear in the jenkins server) you can use the [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) step to achieve what you want.

You will have to transform each node name into a map entry representing the parallel execution branch and then run them using the `parallel` keyword.
something like:

```
def hosts = HOSTNAMES.split(',')
def executions = hosts.collectEntries { host ->
    ["Running on ${host}" : {
        node(host) {
            // The code to run on each node
            stage("Execution") {
                echo 'example code on #{host}'
                ...
            }
        }
    }]
}
parallel executions
```

You can also run it in one line if you want:

```
parallel hosts.collectEntries { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this snippet.

Comment: If you are using a declarative pipeline then yes it should reside under the `stage -> steps -> script` directive.

Comment: Where can I find similar usecases in Jenkins documentation page or any other link for reference? Could you please share that?

Comment: @Saro you mean something like [This](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/)?

Comment: Thanks much for this help! Yes, i am looking out for this kind of documentation link.
Besides Jenkins documentation, if you have any other similar links/websites/github links please do share me.

Comment: In the above multiple host execution snippet, how to make node as one agent and run the script on the node?

Comment: when `HOSTNAMES` contains only one host, it will execute only on it.